# How do I prevent my Elastic Beanstalk app from showing as unhealthy if my post deploy takes a long time?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I my `.ebextensions/00.command.config`, I have:

```
container_commands:
  00_download_models:
    command: "./download.py"
```

In `download.py`, I have some code that downloads a lot of files (around 20GB). That takes time and I'd like that to finish before Elastic Beanstalk attempts to boot my app. But in `/var/log/web.stdout.log`, I see:

```
Jun 27 19:42:46 ip-172-31-46-211 web: [2020-06-27 19:42:46 +0000] [3997] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 3997)
Jun 27 19:42:46 ip-172-31-46-211 web: Loading generator
Jun 27 19:42:46 ip-172-31-46-211 web: using device: cpu
```

`Loading generator` is what I print in my `application.py`. This is a `flask` app, if that matters. It appears to attempt to restart the app multiple times while downloading.

What can I do to first finish `download.py`, THEN attempt to start the app?

Comment: 20GB dependencies will slow down everything. I think you should consider creating custom AMI with all these dependencies, or at least attempt to put them in S3 and download from S3.

Comment: They are being downloaded from S3

Comment: How long does it take to download them if you do it manually? Your EB setup maybe timing out?

Comment: Maybe 20 or so min?

Comment: If you check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elasticbeanstalkcommand), the default timeout is 600 seconds (10 minutes). Have you increased it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EB, you can **disable health checks** during deployments. For example in console you can do this as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

Obviously, you can also do it form CLI if you use it for deployments.

They still may show as unhealthy, but won't lead to failed deployments.